# How to stop of a Thread when it finishes its work?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

I am working on web application on Java EE.

I have created a thread in my `ServletContextLitner` so it does some entries in database in background and user is sent to it's homepage.

My question is that how to stop this thread when it is done with its work?

Comment: If you don't have a infinite loop inside your Thread's run method it will stop after finishing the work itself.

Comment: If it's a thread that finishes its work - why do you need to implement `ServletContextListener` ?

Comment: Well. If you want to `stop` the thread while it is executing , you could *interrupt* it. And in the `run()` method, check if the thread is `interrupted()` and return if *true*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Thread has a `run()` method that is executed when the Thread is started (`start()`).

The method `run()` contains all the logic of the `Thread`. When the method `run()` finishes, the Thread is marked for gc.

Which means, just finish the `run()` and the `JVM` will do the rest.

Comment: "When the method `run()` finishes, the Thread is marked for gc." Incorrect - a `Thread`, like any other object, can be garbage collectable when there are no references to it. There might still be references to it after `run()` finishes.

Comment: Ah, but I didn't say "garbage collected" any object can be marked for garbage collection, but only during the second step it will be dealocated, only if there are no strong pointers to the object :P

Answer (score 2):

```
public void run(){

//Do you work here

return; //However not necessary to mention. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, when the run() is finished, thread will stop by jvm, but in your case, since your context is a listener, so I think there is a loop in you run() method. So, I think you can us a flag in your loop, and when flag is false, just break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Java EE specs indicate you are NOT allowed to create your own threads in a Java EE application.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/restrictions-142267.html

> Why is thread creation and management disallowed?
>
> The EJB specification assigns to the EJB container the responsibility for managing threads. Allowing enterprise bean instances to create and manage threads would interfere with the container's ability to control its components' lifecycle. Thread management is not a business function, it is an implementation detail, and is typically complicated and platform-specific. Letting the container manage threads relieves the enterprise bean developer of dealing with threading issues. Multithreaded applications are still possible, but control of multithreading is located in the container, not in the enterprise bean.